# JavaScript setTimeout not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, timer, settimeout

I can't understand. In Chrome debugger it works, but when I turn it off and refresh the page, my div is clear.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function banner_change(span) {
      if ($(span).hasClass('show')) {
        $(span).removeClass('show');
      }
    }

    $('div#spec_banner span').each(function () { 
      if (!$(this).hasClass('show')) {
        $(this).addClass('show')
      }
      setTimeout(banner_change(this), 5000);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Thank you for answering.

Comment: I understand the problem. setTimer sends function to the end of the script, so jquery.each isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

several problems , syntax and scope

When using setTimeout without an anonymous function, syntax is:

```
setTimeout(banner_change, 5000); /* no () */
```

To pass arguments need to do:

```
setTimeout(function(){
      banner_change(this);
}, 5000);
```

But also, back to scope, `this` has lost context inside setTimeout ( is now likely `window`) so need to assign to variable outside of setTimeout

```
$('div#spec_banner span').each(function () { 
  if (!$(this).hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).addClass('show')
  }
    var span =this
  setTimeout(function(){
      banner_change(span);
  }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Technically not a *syntax* error - it will evaluate just fine and keep doing it's thing - it surely won't act as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue:

```
  setTimeout(banner_change(this), 5000);
```

You're actually calling banner_change here - try

```
  setTimeout(function(){
      banner_change('div#spec_banner span');
  }, 5000);
```

The call you were originally doing was executing `banner_change` immediately and passing the return value to `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass function reference not function invocation result.

```
setTimeout( $.proxy(banner_change, this), 5000);
```

$.proxy wrapper for the function reference will ensure your function is invoked with the "this" context.

Answer (score 0):

get the function out of document ready for it to work properly

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: it is the answer! the problem is with function banner_change that should be defined out of document ready function